# Android Apk not working after using proguard

Tags: android, proguard, classnotfoundexception, android-proguard

I'm new to proguard, and I got an issue that I don't know how to fix. I was able to create a signed apk of my app using proguard and to install it on my device, but when I try to launch the app I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application test.myapp.first.com.CustomApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.myapp.first.com.CustomApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.myapp.first.com-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test.myapp.first.com-2/lib/arm, /data/app/test.myapp.first.com-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I tried to use -keep class in order to exclude the class and also Activity/Application subclasses from the                                                     obfuscation, and yes, in the android manifest the path to the application class is the full package path. I've decompiled the signed apk and actually the java class is placed in the correct path.

Any idea on how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I've always found this a painful process. Basically I start by keeping everything in my packages and then slowly making the keeps more specific until it stops working. Then I back off on the one that is not working and try again somewhere else in the package tree. There may be a better way, but my personal opinion is that proguard is a pain in the .....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proguard config from sdk, it's located in `tools/proguard/`, for example, `proguard-android-optimize.txt`.